# Rendering the text edges for browser

Tags: css, fonts

Hi when I using photoshop the fonts are so smooth and doesn't look pixelated. Now I have seen this on many different sites, how smooth the fonts are and don't look pixelated at all.

I was wondering if there was a property or something that i can use to get the text smooth in css.

For example ---> http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10533/text-smoothing/p1

see where it says '[Solved] Text Smoothing', how do i get the text that smooth without having to make the font oo big, I'm using "Arial Black" font on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the link you shared quite a large degree of font smoothness has to do with the browser or OS that the type is displayed on.

For example, Windows uses ClearType technology to help smooth fonts. And yet, on a Windows machine, the font will look slightly different in each browser. I have noticed this effect while testing various sites across the major browsers.

Another thing about 'Generic' fonts (those included in most machines by default), is that the base font might differ slightly OS to OS etc. So for that reason you may look into a custon CSS3 font on your site so that you know that users with support for custom fonts will have a very similar appearance.

If you are set on using one of the web safe fonts, I would recommend testing various font-weights and seeing if one renders particularly well in most browsers. As the font weight correlates directly with the approximate size on screen this will affect the pixels being used and it is possible that some weights perform poorly in ClearType and related font smoothing technologies.

I would try finding an Arial lookalike otherwise.